# Complex Parameter Binding (array of nested class) in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, parameters

**Having:**

```
public class Range
{
    public double Min{get;set;}
    public double Max{get;set;}
}

public class CustomParameters
{
    public List<Range> SelectedRanges{get;set;}
    public List<int> SelectedTypes{get;set;}
}
```

I made a custom method in the `FooController` like this:

```
[Route("Operation")]    
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Foo> Operation([FromUri] CustomParameters parameters)
{
     //some code to return what I'm looking for.
}
```

**Question**
What the query string looks like when we have combination of array and custom types with nested objects?
Here is the query which I'm using but not working.

```
api/Foo/Operation?
    SelectedRanges.Min=0&
    SelectedRanges.Max=10&
    SelectedRanges.Min=100&
    SelectedRanges.Max=200&
    SelectedTypes=1&
    SelectedTypes=2
```

Comment: `params` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh thanks it was a typo

Comment: you might change the method to `HttpPost` and post data as `json`. Pretty easier that way.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh I found the answer! we should use `[]` in these cases.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. In this case we can use indexing with `[]` to group attributes of an instance in a collection, so the first `Min` and `Max` values together maps to a single `Range` instance in the `SelectedRanges` list.

```
api/Foo/Operation?
    SelectedRanges[0].Min=0&
    SelectedRanges[0].Max=10&
    SelectedRanges[1].Min=100&
    SelectedRanges[1].Max=200&
    SelectedTypes=1&
    SelectedTypes=2
```

Comment: that works. But again I would stick to a `POST` when sending complex objects.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh I do agree, but it was interesting to me to find how the query string would look like in this case.